# JavaScript: как сохранить элементы в объект и получить как html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Допустим, есть некий HTML-код:

```
<div id="main">

<div id="sub1">123</div>
<div id="sub2">456</div>
<div id="sub3">789</div>

</div>
```

Нужно, сохранить каждый блок `sub*` в объект-массив, чтобы позже получить доступ к этим блокам. Например:

```
var i = 0;
var arr = {};

    $('#main').find("div").each(function()
    {
      arr[i] = {'elem':$(this)};
      i++;
    });
```

А вот как теперь, например, получить доступ к элементу, допустим номер 3, если теперь у нас это объект, а не HTML-node?

```
arr[3].а_дальше_что?
```

Хочется, чтобы было как-то так: `arr[3].text();` // получить текст блока

Comment: `var arr = [];`

Comment: Для заполнения массива, я полагаю, вам больше подойдёт функция [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну так и обратитесь к полю объекта

```js
var i = 0;
var arr = {};

$('#main').find("div").each(function() {
  arr[i] = {
    'elem': $(this)
  };
  i++;
});

console.log(arr[2].elem.text());
console.log(arr[2].elem.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="sub1">123</div>
  <div id="sub2">456</div>
  <div id="sub3"><span>789</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Как говорится: "Все элементарное - просто!". Не посоветуете какой-то js-редактор, а то в обычном блокноте невозможно выучить js?

Comment: @Trancer https://learn.javascript.ru/editor

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы получить HTML у DOM-элемента, есть такое свойство `outerHTML`. Из jQuery-объекта надо получить DOM-элемент и обратиться к этому свойству:

```
arr[3].get(0).outerHTML
```

Comment: Про свойство `outerHTML` знаю, но не знал как к нему подобраться. Все из-за того, что пишу по привычку в блокноте)) надо подыскать для тих нужд какую-то JS IDE. Большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Trancer проголосуйте за, раз вам помог мой ответ. По поводу IDE чисто для FrontEnd можно, к примеру, WebStorm.